# Log exception not working after switching threads with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm making a request with retrofit2 and trying to log the exception, but default Android Log does not print exception into LogCat. But `e.printStackTrace();` do print exception. Android Log also starts to print exception when remove `observeOn`, `subscribeOn`. What is the problem with Android Log, should Log work on any thread?

```
api.loadNotifations()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(notifications -> {
                }, e -> {
                  Log.e("tag", "msg", e);
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  throw new OnErrorNotImplementedException(e);
                })));
```